# Gulp is creating a directory instead of a file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-clean-css

I want gulp to spit out a `style.min.css`:

```
// Minify
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    gulp.src('css/style.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/style.min.css'))
});
```

it is minifying the `.css` but instead is creating a directory with a style.css in it:

```
css/style.min.css/style.css
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`gulp.dest`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options) writes to directories. You should add a rename step before piping to `gulp.dest`.

```
.pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
```

You should be able to use the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) module for this.

Comment: Got it. I was telling gulp to create a directory in dest named style.min.css. Thank you very much!